# How to use Graphics2D outside of the main function?

Tags: java, swing

I draw something on the panel and than I would like to move it or draw something over it, when the user presses a button. In this example, the button is called lower and the event to do, when it is pressed would be something like this:

```
    private static void lowerIt(){      

    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 436, 22, 42);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 537, 22, 42);

    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 437, 22, 40);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 538, 22, 40);
}
```

the problem is, the method needs to get g2d, but if I do it again like this:

```
    private static void lowerIt(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 436, 22, 42);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 537, 22, 42);

    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 437, 22, 40);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.fillRect(284, 538, 22, 40);
}
```

I get nullpointerexception error and a few others. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to pass the "g" (Graphics) to lowerIt from somewhere, otherwise it will be null and the whole method will fail.

For example, if you override paintComponent:

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        lowerIt(g);
    }
```

That way, you are calling the method with a graphics object.

In your case, you should make the following change (add the graphics object to the call to gSpusti():

```
        spust.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        gSpusti(f2.getGraphics());
    }});
```

Comment: I tried to do something, but it's not working, same error. Whole code is here: http://piratepad.net/FbbEn2cGfm lowerIt is called gSpusti.

Comment: *"Whole code is here:"*   For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  And post it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32652464/edit) ..

Comment: I've added a change to the answer to show you exactly where you were not passing the graphics object correctly.   I see two little red trucks on the right of the screen, so I guess it works.